# Access the window service stop method in other class c#

Tags: c#, service

I am working on window service and I want to call the stop method of service in other class so that I can stop the window service.

My **service main class**

```
 static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new MyService() 
        };
        
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            ServicesToRun.RunInteractive();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to execute Service as a Console app for testing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="servicesToRun"></param>
    public static void RunInteractive(this ServiceBase[] servicesToRun)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Services running in interactive mode.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Using Reflection to get the OnStart method of the service(s)
        MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
        {
            Console.Write("Starting {0}...", service.ServiceName);
            onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } }); // Call the OnStart(string[]) method
            Console.Write("Started\n\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press the ENTER key to stop the services and end the process...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Using Reflection to get the OnStop method of the service(s)
        MethodInfo onStopMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStop", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
        {
            Console.Write("Stopping {0}...", service.ServiceName);
            onStopMethod.Invoke(service, null); // Call the OnStop() method
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("All services stopped. Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**AppConfigSettings File**

```
 private void ValidateAppConfigSettingsValues()
   {
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
            {
                // notify the users
              
               //  stop the service here.
            }
    }
```

I tried to add the code in the suggested link [How to start or stop a Windows Service using C#..](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-start-or-stop-a-windows-service-using-C-Sharp/)

```
 ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyServiceName");

if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
  (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
    service.Start();
else    service.Stop();
```

But it is giving me error **Service Service1 was not found on computer**

Also, I am running the service by **Interactive mode** i.e. by debugging.

Is there any way to archive this.

I want to stop the service if the value is not found in the app.config files.

Is there any way we can call the service stop method in the AppConfigSettings.cs file.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-start-or-stop-a-windows-service-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: @JackA. I tried this and it gives me error "Service Service1 was not found on computer '.'.

Comment: run visual studio as administrator

Comment: Getting same error. I am running service by Interactive mode i.e. by debugging.

Comment: The `ServiceController` approach won't work when you run interactively because it isn't actually running as a service in that case, it's running as a regular command-line app. Does that really matter, though? Do you really need it to stop itself when you're debugging?

Comment: Yes actually I want to test this and several other scenario, I don't want to deploy this as service for that. Is there way to test this in interactive mode.

Comment: The simplest way to test when debugging is to set a breakpoint in the code that stops the service. You could extract the code that stops the service into a class that determines if it's running as a service or console app and uses the appropriate way to stop it. To me that seems like overkill for debugging. I don't think there is a way to verify that the `ServiceController` code is working correctly other than running as a service.